# Firebase webhooks

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I have purchased the flame plan for cloud function.I am deploying my webhook using dialogue flow still getting same error:

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/
>   jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/:8080
>
> at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
>
> at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)

```
'use strict';

var https = require ('https');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const DialogFlowApp = require('actions-on-google').DialogFlowApp;



exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, 
response) => {


let action = request.body.queryResult.action;

var chat = "here is a sample response: trump sucks";

response.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');

if (action!= 'input.getStockPrice'){
  console.log('Inside input function');
 response.send(buildChatResponse("I'm sorry, I don't know this"));
 return;
 }

getStockPrice (response);

});

function getStockPrice (CloudFnResponse) {


 var pathString = "users/2";

 var request = https.get({
    host: "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/",
    path: pathString,


   }, function (response) {
    var json = "";
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log("received JSON response: " + chunk);
        json += chunk;


    });

    response.on('end', function(){
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(json);
        console.log("1");
        var stockPrice = jsonData.name

        console.log ("the stock price received is:" + stockPrice);

        CloudFnResponse.send(buildChatResponse(stockPrice ));

      });

   });

   }

     function buildChatResponse(chat) {
    return JSON.stringify({"fulfillmentText": chat});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the full URL, not a partial URL.  You're missing the scheme part.  It's probably https:

```
host: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/",
```